# Trouble shooting PHPUnit xdebug remote debugging with PHPStorm

Tags: php, xdebug, remote-debugging, phpstorm

I am trying to get Xdebug remote debugging to work, I am using PHPStorm as my IDE.
My webserver/code is hosted on a remote machine (amazon ec2).

I have the following lines in my php.ini on my remote server (PHP CLI since I am doing PHPUnit debugging)

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Since I am programming from my home network, I opened port 9000 on my personal router.
I have PHPStorm's xdebug server set to point to the remote server on port 80 with Xdebug as it's Debugger.

Now when I try to debug a PHPUnit test from PHPStorm it just says 
'waiting for incoming connections with ide key '12115' 
Except, it picks a random ide key every single time (I want to hope that PHPUnit is setting the idekey on the server itself)

I have been trying to get this to work for over 10 hours, I have tried defining my a specific remote_host in the php.ini instead of using remote_connect_back but that also did not work. I have tried setting an idekey in php.ini and that did not work as well.

Is there anyway to confirm that Xdebug is working as intended on the webserver side? How can I test my Xdebug settings without using Phpstorm, I don't know if it is a connection issue between my home network and the remote server or what.

Any guidance to help narrow down the issue would be great.

Comment: I have recently tried to create an ssh-tunnel for port 9000 from my local laptop to the remote server before trying to debug and it still does not seem to work ( I changed the setting xdebug.remote_host to the loopback address 127.0.0.1). Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd enable xdebug logging and also use tcpdump to see if the connection is being made, then enable debug logging for PhpStorm: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1202. Try if it works with zero configuration approach: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/.

Answer (score 5):

I know that the question is a little old, but since I had the same problem and just found a solution, I have decided to post here for anyone interested.

> My solution is heavily based on the one provided by Rafael Dohms in
>   his blog post entitled: [Debugging PHPUnit Tests in NetBeans with
>   XDebug](http://blog.doh.ms/2011/05/13/debugging-phpunit-tests-in-netbeans-with-xdebug/)

### Environment

- IDE: PHPStorm 6.0.2
- Server: WAMP Server (32-bit & PHP 5.4.3) 2.2E
- XDebug: 2.2.2

### XDebug

```
zend_extension=c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9.dll
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=c:/wamp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remote.log
```

> The above configuration parameters go into the "php.ini" file for CLI. For the default WAMP installation, the full path to this file is: *C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini*

### PHPStorm

First of all, you must create a "Server Configuration" (google "Creating a Server Configuration - JetBrains" for the official doc on the subject) specifying "Xdebug" as the "Debugger".

Then, create a new "PHP Remote Debug Configuration" (google "Creating and Editing Run/Debug Configurations - JetBrains" for the official doc on the subject) specifying the following values under the "Configuration" section:

- Servers: *the server created above*
- Ide key: PHPSTORM

Now, select that configuration and press the "Debug" button (or "Shift + F9"). PHPStorm will display the "Debug" panel and show the message: *Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'*

Finally, "run" you PHPUnit test. There are several ways. One of them is:

- Right click the name of the file the PHPUnit test resides in.
- Select "Run *file name*"

That's it! XDebug will take control from here on.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Xdebug 2.2.0RC1, then the remote debug-log (http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) will tell you succeeded and failed connection attempts. That might pinpoint whether the problem is on the Xdebug side, or phpstorm side.

Comment: So doing this I was able to gather something at least: When I run a php file through php-cli or through 'phpunit' on the command line, there are entries placed onto the xdebug log. But when I run tests through my phpstorm remotely, I can get the results of the test but there are no entries added into the xdebug log. I still can't resolve the problem though.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that I had the xdebug config in `/etc/php/fpm/php.ini`, but php-cli uses `/etc/php/cli/php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it took me a day to get it to work, I will sum up, what in learned:

Make sure, you are changing the right php.ini, XAMPP uses another php.ini and php version, than the one preinstalled on OS X Mavericks.

Define a logfile and if nothing is written into it, you a changing the wrong php.ini

In phpstorm you can validate your server connection and gain insight, if you are working on the right php.ini or what is still wrong.

You have to change settings for debug (might be worth to change the port to 9001), the server, all in phpstorm preferences and set up.

You have to set the php language level and the Interpreter (use the one your Apache mysql php configuration uses) e.g. /Application/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin, click on ... to see Php and if debugger is attached. You might have to use another version of xdebug.

In Servers you have to define Host as

```
http://yourdefinitionofprojectonlocalhost
```

with usually Port 80 and Xdebug. Here it is essential to validate the remote environment.

Under debug you can set the Debug Port, if you change it to 9001, change it in the php.ini too, choose Can Accept external Connections.

If you do not enable Start to listen for PHP Debug Connection, you have no hope of getting it to work (Icon in upper right corner or down in Run menu).

In Edit Configurations... you have to define a PHP Web Application to be able to use Debug in the Run menu.

It took me a day to get it to work. The main issues being editing the wrong php.ini (do not forget to restart apache after edit) and the fact, that xdebug did not work with the php version.

As you can see I tried a lot of options in my php.ini and ended up using version of xdebug in found in my mamp directory:

```
;zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-   zts-20121212/xdebug.so"

[xdebug]
;xdebug.var_display_max_children = 999
;xdebug.var_display_max_data = 99999
;xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 100
;xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.remote_port=9001
;xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
;xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
;xdebug.remote_host=localhost
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/Users/mypath/tmp
xdebug.remote_log=/Users/mypath/xdebug.log
;xdebug.remote_mode=req

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
```

Wish you more speedy success than I had.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it started working when I changed the port to something other than 9000.

Phpstorm's phpunit command was now:

`/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9002 -dxdebug.remote_host=10.0.2.2 /var/www/application/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --bootstrap /var/www/application/tests/Bootstrap.php --configuration /var/www/application/tests/phpunit.xml <testfile> --teamcity`